# Is there a better way of implementing a histogram?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, histogram

I have a 2D uint16 numpy array, I want to calculate the histogram for this array.
The function I use is:

```
def calc_hist(source):
    hist = np.zeros(2**16, dtype='uint16')
    for i in range(source.shape[0]):
       for j in range(source.shape[1]):
           hist[source[i, j]] = hist[source[i, j]] + 1
    return hist
```

This function takes too much time to execute.
As I understand, there's a histogram function in the numpy module but I cant figure how to use it.
I've tried:

```
hist,_ = np.histogram(source.flatten(), bins=range(2**16))
```

But I get different results then my own function.
How can I call numpy.histogram to achieve the same result? or is there any other options?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data!

Comment: Could you also fix the code you posted so it actual works?

Comment: it works, you can randomize a uint16 2d array..

Comment: No it doesn't. Cut out the code in your question, paste it into a file or IDE and try and run it.. Even after you fixed the `zeroes`, there are unbalanced brackets in the code

Comment: your code uses the exact numbers, so it is always the range (0, 2^16-1). the numpy histogram defaults to the range (a.min(), a.max()) and then splits into num bins. You may need to explicitly give it the (float) range (0, 2^16) to get results that are similar....

Comment: @CorleyBrigman oh yeah, I see. How can I know then the number of bins? I need manually to search for the first and last index's which are not 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an input with data type `uint16`, [`numpy.bincount`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) should work well:

```
hist = np.bincount(source.ravel(), minlength=2**16)
```

Your function is doing almost exactly what `bincount` does, but `bincount` is implemented in C.

For example, the following checks that this use of `bincount` gives the same result as your `calc_hist` function:

```
In [159]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [160]: x = rng.integers(0, 2**16, size=(1000, 1000))                                      

In [161]: h1 = calc_hist(x)

In [162]: h2 = np.bincount(x.ravel(), minlength=2**16)

In [163]: (h1 == h2).all()  # Verify that they are the same.
Out[163]: True
```

Check the performance with ipython `%timeit` command.  You can see that using `bincount` is *much* faster.

```
In [164]: %timeit calc_hist(x)
2.66 s ± 21.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [165]: %timeit np.bincount(x.ravel(), minlength=2**16)
3.13 ms ± 100 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Corley Brigman pointed out, passing `bins=range(x)` determines the bin edges [1]. So, you will end up with x-1 bins with corresponding edges [0, 1), [1, 2), ..., [x-1, x].

In your case, you will have 2^16-1 bins. To fix it, simply use `range(2**16+1)`.

[1] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html?highlight=histogram#numpy.histogram

Comment: This is only going to be the correct answer if the very last bin is the only incorrect bin